# How to change a string list to a list of integers?

Tags: python, string

I have a list that combines inputs from two sources, that ends up looking like this 'pde_fin' given below. I need to extract the integer values of the elements in the list for further processing. However, the second set of numbers seem to give an error ("invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'1118'").

```
pde_fin =['2174', '2053', '2080', '2160', '2065', "'1118'", "'1098'", "'2052'", "'2160'", "'2078'", "'2161'", "'2134'", "'2091'", "'2089'", "'2105'", "'2109'", "'2077'", "'2057'"]
for i in pde_fin:
    print(int(i))
```

Comment: You have values like `"'1118'"`. You have first get rid of the quotes.

Comment: @Thierry Your duplicate mark is not completely accurate.  This list contains both number strings _and_ number strings quotes.

Comment: I've seen that just after closing and reopened it. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 5):

The simplest fix is to strip the single quotes:

```
for i in pde_fin:
    print(int(i.strip("'")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to correct your values:

```
pde_fin =['2174', '2053', '2080', '2160', '2065', "'1118'", "'1098'", "'2052'", "'2160'", "'2078'", "'2161'", "'2134'", "'2091'", "'2089'", "'2105'", "'2109'", "'2077'", "'2057'"]
for i in pde_fin:
    print(int(i.replace("'",'')))
```